# no-list option for newly created float

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex, endfloat

I have create some new floats and i have place them in end of the document using endfloat, i need to hide the list like nofiglist is it possible.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\let\normalcaption=\caption
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{float}
\let\caption=\normalcaption


\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[nofiglist]{endfloat}

\newcommand{\lipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada consequat mollis. Duis viverra vestibulum quam id vehicula. Donec vel tellus a orci adipiscing euismod. Suspendisse lacinia metus lorem. Vivamus pellentesque, lacus quis blandit tincidunt, elit nunc ullamcorper enim, ut laoreet metus risus sed neque. Sed ac nibh ante, pellentesque vehicula sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel libero leo. Donec aliquam placerat arcu, et ultrices leo semper et. Curabitur dignissim, eros vitae dignissim porta, velit arcu vehicula tortor, vel blandit sapien magna in risus.}%


\newfloat{map}{tbp}{lomap}
\floatname{map}{Map}
%\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}{Maps}

\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{photo}{Photo}
%\DeclareDelayedFloat{photo}{Photo}
\newfloat{scheme}{htbp}{scheme}
\floatname{scheme}{scheme}


\makeatletter
\def\sidewaysphoto{\@rotfloat{photo}}
\let\endsidewaysphoto\end@rotfloat

\newenvironment{sidewaysphoto*}{\@rotdblfloat{photo}}{\end@rotdblfloat}



\makeatother

\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}[mmm]{Maps}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{photo}[ppp]{Photos}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysphoto}{photo}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{sidewaysphoto}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myPhoto}
    \caption{xxxxxxxMy Photo 1}
\end{sidewaysphoto}

\lipsum
\begin{photo}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myPhoto}
    \caption{My Photo 2}
\end{photo}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myFigure}
    \caption{My Figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\begin{map}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myMap}
    \caption{My Map}
\end{map}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that these packages come with manuals which explain the options?  Well, [nolists] turns off ALL lists, just like it says.

Comment: @ John Kormylo  i wnt the output like nofiglist for map and photo

Comment: Which is what [nolists] does.  Having lists for some but not others would be more tricky.

Comment: @Shalu `\SetupDelayedFloat{map}{nolist}`. See also: endfloat documentation, section 8.3 "Other floating environments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with

```
\SetupDelayedFloat{map}{nolist}
```

See also: endfloat documentation, section 8.3 "Other floating environments"